# Creating a Glowing Sphere in Java3D

Tags: java, opengl, java-3d

I'm looking for a way to reproduce this foggy-sphere-glowing effect using Java3D.

http://bzflag.org/screenshots/bzfi0021.jpg
http://bzflag.org/screenshots/bzfi0019.jpg
http://bzflag.org/screenshots/bzfi0022.jpg

I'm creating a transform group with a point light source and an emissive-material-sphere, but I can't reproduce the foggyness.

Ideas?

Thanks!

============ SOLUTION (Thanks to Ricket)  ===========

```
    try
    {
        TextureLoader myLoader = new TextureLoader( new File("./data/grad.png").toURI().toURL(), this );

        ImageComponent2D myImage = myLoader.getImage( );

        Raster raster = new Raster( );
        raster.setPosition( new Point3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ) );
        raster.setType( Raster.RASTER_COLOR );
        raster.setSize( 50, 50);
        raster.setImage( myImage );

        TransparencyAttributes ta =  new TransparencyAttributes( TransparencyAttributes.BLENDED, 0.0f );
        Appearance app = new Appearance();
        app.setTransparencyAttributes( ta );

        objScale.addChild( new OrientedShape3D(raster, app, OrientedShape3D.ROTATE_ABOUT_POINT, new Point3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f )));


    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) { throw new RuntimeException(); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the "sphere" is actually a 2D sprite drawn in 3D space as a billboard, and then a matching color light also 'drawn' at its position. The fogginess is just a 2D gradient of the image.

This is just my best guess from having played the game though, I haven't looked at the source.

Comment: Thanks!  As far as I can tell, that's the correct suggestion.  The Java3D object is called an OrientedShape3D - in case any one else wants the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

The Article [Understanding Lighting in the Java 3D API](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3622246/Understanding-Lighting-in-the-Java-3D-API.htm) explains how to setup the lighting parameters. If you can't simulate the glowing effect with one sphere you could try to put a smaller brigther one into a colored transparent sphere.

Answer (score 0):

You might try [looking at the code](http://bzflag.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/bzflag/tags/v2_0_14/src/geometry/).  They even have a [guide](http://my.bzflag.org/w/BZFlag_Source#Organization).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, it appears they're using a totally different library and different language.

Comment: The OpenGL command sequences should be the same no matter what binding you're using.

Comment: Java3D doesn't use OpenGL command sequences, it's a high-level, scene-graph-based 3D library. You deal with trees of nodes.

Comment: Sorry, you're exactly right.  I had somehow assumed the OP was using a thin Java binding for OpenGL.